# Copy to clipboard without document.execommand()

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard

Is there ANY way to copy to a computer's clipboard WITHOUT using document.execCommand() ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: Reading between the lines, it sounds like you have already tried `document.execCommand()` and it didn't work. You are more likely to get useful answers if you describe what you've done, what platform you're working on and generally why you want some other solution.

Comment: @IngoBürk `document.execCommand()` has been deprecated, so this is a legitimate question. It’s not the same as the other.

Answer (score -1):

you can get the files from here [Clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/)

```html
<p id="docopy2">Your content comes here </p>
</p>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#docopy2')">Copy</button><br><br><br>
```